# Is it possible to deactivate button while computing some jobs

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a submit button which I expect the following behavior:

```
1. Click submit button
2. Deactivate button and run some time consuming jobs
3. Once the jobs are done, enable the submit button
```

What I need to help is, is it possible to return ‘disabled’ state at first (because jobs are executing) and then return an ‘active’ state once jobs are done. Generally speaking, is it possible to deactivate a button for some time spans?

Thank you for your help!

Here are my codes:

```
dbc.Button(‘Clickme’,
id = ‘btn’,
disabled = False
)

@app.callback(
Output(“btn”, “disabled”),
Input(“btn”, “n_clicks”),
State(“btn”, “disabled”),
)
def deactivate_btn_temporary(n1, disabled):
print(n1, disabled)
# execute some computing jobs
# while jobs is running: return disabled (need help)
# Once jobs are done:    return not disabled (need)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with this paramteter: disabled (a value equal to: 'disabled' or 'DISABLED' | boolean; optional): Indicates whether the user can interact with the element, find more in the official documentation https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/button